# Stack Overflow in random number generator

Tags: c#, random, stack-overflow

For some reason, this code works fine when I don't use a seed in the Random class, but if I try to use DateTime.Now to get a more random number, I get a StackOverflowException! My class is really simple. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? See MakeUniqueFileName.

```
public class TempUtil
{
    private int strcmp(string s1, string s2)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
                if (s1[i] != s2[i]) return 0;
            return 1;
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    private int Uniqueness(object randomObj)
    {
        switch (randomObj.ToString())
        {
            case "System.Object":
            case "System.String":
                return randomObj.ToString()[0];
            case "System.Int32":
                return int.Parse(randomObj.ToString());
            case "System.Boolean":
                return strcmp(randomObj.ToString(), "True");
            default:
                return Uniqueness(randomObj.ToString());
        }
    }
    public string MakeUniqueFileName()
    {
        return "C:\\windows\\temp\\" + new Random(Uniqueness(DateTime.Now)).NextDouble() + ".tmp";
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the point about seeding that you seed once and then get the random sequence from that seed?

Comment: I'd venture that method `Uniqueness` is a strange method indeed. Can you explain the design principal behind it? Wouldn't it be better to check against `Type` rather than `.ToString`. It's probably not doing what you expect in the case of `System.String`

Comment: Any reason you can't use Path.GetTempFileName  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx

Comment: First off it is completely unclear what you mean by "more random". Second, *Random is already seeded with the current time*, so seeding it with the current time isn't "more" or "less" *anything*. It's the same.

Comment: `strcmp` -> `string.CompareTo`, `MakeUniqueFileName` -> `Path.GetTempFileName`  - don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: Third **why are you doing any of this**? Is there something wrong with calling GetTempFileName to *get a temporary file name*?

Comment: The `strcmp` really got me. ^^ And `return Uniqueness(randomObj.ToString());` is the same as `return Uniqueness(randomObj);`.

Comment: `strcmp(randomObj.ToString(), "True")` this made me die, not just a little :(

Comment: Fourth, **why are you going for randomness when what you want is uniqueness**?  Randomness is not at all the same thing as uniqueness. If you want a *unique identifier* then make a Guid; Guids are guaranteed to be *unique* but not guaranteed to be *random*.

Comment: Fifth, **why are you catching the index out of range exception**?  You should write the code so that it *cannot possibly be thrown*.  You should **never, ever, ever** catch a null reference exception or an index out of range exception or an argument null exception; they should all be *impossible* because *you wrote the code correctly so that they never happen*. These exceptions indicate *bugs*; fix the bugs, don't catch the exceptions.

Comment: Path.GetTempFileName returns some strange path in in C:\Users\AppData. I need the real Windows temp path.

Comment: @RagingDave: And yet you hard coded it to `c:\windows\temp`. What if my Windows install is on another drive? What if my temp directory is not in my Windows directory. And please read Eric Lippert's comments again.

Comment: @RagingDave: It's not a *strange* path - it's the path you should use to write a temporary file.

Comment: @Raging It's not strange - it IS the Users Temporary Folder, as opposed to the system wide one.

Comment: @RagingDave: That strange path **is the real windows temp path**. You think that GetTempFileName is going to return you some path to something *other* than the real temp path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short:

It should say

```
    switch (randomObj.GetType().ToString())
```

instead of

```
    switch (randomObj.ToString())
```

But even then this isn't very clever.

Comment: @RagingDave: If you want to use different handling for different types, use `is`. But fundamentally this is just nasty code - there are *much* better approaches, and you don't need any code *at all*, given that there's already an API method for this.

Comment: @RagingDave Although my answer *technically* solves your problem by pointing you to the mistake in your algorithm, I (in accord with Jon Skeet) strongly discourage you to use such a coding style. If you want to improve your style, start by reading and considering all of **Eric Lipperts** hints to your question. There is nothing bad about *not* reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 11):

You're calling `DateTime.Now.ToString()`, which doesn't give you one of the strings you're checking for... so you're recursing, calling it with the same string... which *still* isn't one of the strings you're looking for.

You don't need to use `Random` to demonstrate the problem. This will do it very easily:

```
Uniqueness(""); // Tick, tick, tick... stack overflow
```

What did you *expect* it to be doing? It's entirely unclear what your code is *meant* to be doing, but I suggest you ditch the `Uniqueness` method completely. In fact, I suggest you get rid of the whole class, and use [`Path.GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a `DateTime` instance to your `Uniqueness` method.

This falls through and calls itself with `ToString` - on a `DateTime` instance this will be a formatted `DateTime` string (such as `"21/01/2011 13:13:01"`).

Since this string doesn't match any of your switch cases (again), the method calls itself again, but the result of calling `ToString` on a string is the same string.

You have caused an infinite call stack that results in the `StackOverflowException`.

There is no need to call `Uniquness` - when creating a `Random` instance, it will be based on the current time anyways.

I suggest reading [Random numbers](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) from the C# in depth website.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter-less constructor of `Random` already uses the current time as seed value. It uses the time ticks, used internally to represent a `DateTime`.

A problem with this approach, however, is that the time clock ticks very slowly compared to the CPU clock frequency. If you create a new instance of `Random` each time you need a random value, it may be, that the clock did not tick between two calls, thus generating the same random number twice.

You can simply solve this problem by creating a single instance of `Random`.

```
public class TempUtil { 
    private static readonly Random random = new Random();

    public string MakeUniqueFileName()
    {
        return @"C:\windows\temp\" + random.NextDouble() + ".tmp";     
    } 
}
```

This will generate very good random numbers.

---

By the way

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()
```

automatically creates an empty temporary file with a unique name and returns the full path of that file.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest just using a static field for Random unless you've only got a single thread - Random isn't thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Where to begin.
1. There is already a string compare. Use it. It has been debugged.
2. Your Unique function is illogical. The first two case items return a 'S' perhaps cast to an int. You have neglected the break on the first case.

Your third case is like this:
if (x =="System.Int32") return int.Parse("System.Int32");
That may return 32, or a parse error.

Your fourth case is like this:
if (x == "System.Boolean") return strcmp("System.Boolean", "True");
Your default case is called recursevly (sp) causing the stack overflow (see comment above)

In order fix this program, I recommend you read at least one good book on C#, then rethink your program, then write it. Perhaps Javascript would be a better fit.